# Как изменить поле модели Django в функции

Tags: python, django

Допустим есть модель

```
class Person(model.Model):
    first_name = ...
    last_name = ...
```

Нужно написать функцию, которая будет изменять значение поля. Что-то типа того:

```
def change_data(user, field, new_value):
    user.field = new_value


my_user = Person(first_name=Alex, last_name=Cooper)
change_data(my_user, 'first_name', 'Bobby')
```

Как в функции change_data обратиться к полю, если имя поля приходит стракой? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Нужно было написать метод модели:

```
def update_field(self, field, new_value):
    self.__setattr__(field, new_value)
```